# Why does it always print loggers with info severity level?

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I am trying to understand the [boost log tutorial](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html#log.detailed.sources.basic_logger), and I have written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/log/keywords/severity.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>

namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;

// We define our own severity levels
enum severity_level
{
    normal = 0,
    notification,
    warning,
    error,
    critical
};

void logging_function()
{
    // The logger implicitly adds a source-specific attribute 'Severity'
    // of type 'severity_level' on construction
    src::severity_logger< severity_level > slg;

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, normal) << "A regular message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, warning) << "Something bad is going on but I can handle it";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, critical) << "Everything crumbles, shoot me now!";
}

void default_severity()
{
    // The default severity can be specified in constructor.
    src::severity_logger< severity_level > error_lg(keywords::severity = error);

    BOOST_LOG(error_lg) << "An error level log record (by default)";

    // The explicitly specified level overrides the default
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(error_lg, warning) << "A warning level log record (overrode the default)";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    logging_function();
    default_severity();

    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But it is always printing the logs with the `info` severity level, like this:

```
[2014-11-12 14:38:23.476358] [0xbedaf780] [info]    A regular message
[2014-11-12 14:38:23.476967] [0xbedaf780] [info]    Something bad is going on but I can handle it
[2014-11-12 14:38:23.476978] [0xbedaf780] [info]    Everything crumbles, shoot me now!
[2014-11-12 14:38:23.476991] [0xbedaf780] [info]    An error level log record (by default)
[2014-11-12 14:38:23.477002] [0xbedaf780] [info]    A warning level log record (overrode the default)
Hello, world!
```

Why is that? Is it normal to print in standard out? And why isn't it printing the wanted severity level?

---

Even if I have added this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, severity_level level)
{
    static const char* strings[] =
    {
        "NORMAL",
        "NOTIFICATION",
        "WARNING",
        "ERROR",
        "CRITICAL"
    };

    if (static_cast< std::size_t >(level) < sizeof(strings) / sizeof(*strings))
        strm << strings[level];
    else
        strm << static_cast< int >(level);

    return strm;
}
```

The output remains the same. What else have I forgotten?

Comment: I think it's because you didn't provide a function which will convert your severity enum values into strings. did you notice that you don't have "info" in your enum?

Comment: for an example how to implement it, take a look here: https://github.com/godexsoft/pushy/blob/master/src/logging.cpp#L44

Comment: I meet this problem too. It is really frustrating to read Boost docs...

Comment: Have you tried to add the function that convert the severity enum values into strings, as Axel suggested? (if it solves it, add the answer, I am pretty sure it will fix it; it's an old question, I don't remember if I solved it)